# Call to a member function isvalid() on null in laravel5

Tags: laravel-5

When Update an image, it shows follwing error. I cannot update this laravel5 form. can any one find what is my mistake?

> FatalErrorException in SiteadminController.php line 308:
>   Call to a member function isvalid() on null

My file are

Controller

```
public function siteadmin_update_product(Request $request)
    {
        $post = $request->all();

        $cid=$post['product_id'];  

        $product_title = $request->input('product_title');

         $product_price = $request->input('product_price');
          $product_discount_price = $request->input('product_discount_price');
           $product_qty = $request->input('product_qty');
             $deal_description = $request->input('deal_description');
             $select_merchant = $request->input('select_merchant');
             $select_shop = $request->input('select_shop');
             $product_meta_keyword = $request->input('product_meta_keyword');
             $product_meta_description = $request->input('product_meta_description');
             $spec_type = $request->input('spec_type');
             $specification = $request->input('specification');
            $product_size = $request->input('product_size');
        $product_image=Input::file('product_image');


        $v =validator::make($request->all(),
        [

        ]
        );
        if($v->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
        }
        else
        {

             if($product_image->isvalid())
            {
                $extension=$product_image->getClientOriginalName();
                $move_img = explode('.',$extension);
                $fileName=$move_img[0].str_random(8).".".$move_img[1];
                $destinationPath = '../assets/productimage/';
                $uploadSuccess=Input::file('product_image')->move($destinationPath,$fileName);

            $data = array(
            'product_title' => $product_title,

           'product_price' => $product_price,
           'product_discount_price' => $product_discount_price,
           'product_qty' => $product_qty,
           'select_merchant' => $select_merchant,
           'select_shop' => $select_shop,
           'product_meta_keyword' => $product_meta_keyword,
           'product_meta_description' => $product_meta_description,
           'spec_type' => $spec_type,
           'specification' => $specification,
           'product_size' => $product_size,
            'product_image'=> $fileName,

            );
            $ch=Product_model::update_product($data,$cid);
            //$ch=DB::table('le_banner')->where('banner_id',$post['id'])->update($data);
            if($ch > 0)
            {
              Session::flash ('message_update', 'Record Updated Successfully');
             return redirect('siteadmin_manageproduct');
            }

            else 
            {
            return Redirect('siteadmin_editproduct');
            }

    } 
    }
}
```

Model

```
public static function update_product($data,$cid)
   {

      return DB::table('le_product')->where('product_id',$cid)->update($data);  
   }
```

View:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate action="{{action('SiteadminController@siteadmin_update_product')}}" method="POST">

             <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="product_id" value="<?php   echo $row->product_id ?>" id="id">
                <!-- text input -->
                <div class="item form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Product Title*</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="3" name="product_title" placeholder="Product Title" required="required" type="text" value="<?php echo $row->product_title ?>">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item form-group">
                                          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="heard">Select Main Category<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <select id="heard" class="form-control" required>

                                                <option value="press">option 1</option>
                                                <option value="net">option 2</option>
                                                <option value="mouth">option 3</option>
                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="item form-group">
                                          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="heard">Select Sub Category<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <select id="heard" class="form-control" required>

                                                <option value="press">option 1</option>
                                                <option value="net">option 2</option>
                                                <option value="mouth">option 3</option>
                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="item form-group">
                                          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="heard">Select Second Sub Category<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <select id="heard" class="form-control" required>

                                                <option value="press">option 1</option>
                                                <option value="net">option 2</option>
                                                <option value="mouth">option 3</option>
                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="item form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Product Quantity*</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                 <input id="name" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="1" name="product_qty" placeholder="Product Quantity" required="required" type="number" value="<?php echo $row->product_qty ?>">
                  </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="item form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Original Price*</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input id="number" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="2" name="product_price" placeholder="Original Price" required="required" type="number" value="<?php echo $row->product_price ?>">
                  </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="item form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Discounted Price*</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input id="number" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" data-validate-length-range="2" name="product_discount_price" placeholder="Discounted Price" required="required" type="number" value="<?php echo $row->product_discount_price ?>">
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-10"></label>
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="chkPassport">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="chkSelect" checked/>  ( Including tax amount )
                </label>
                </div>
                <div class="item form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-10"></label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                  <input type="number" id="txtUsername" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="product_incometax" placeholder="Tax Amound" value="<?php echo $row->product_incometax ?>" />
                </div>

                </div>

              <div class="item form-group">
                   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Shipping Amount*</label>
                   <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="chkNo">
                      <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" checked/>
                      Free
                  </label>

                  <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="chkYes">
                      <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" />
                      Amount
                  </label>
               </div>
               <div class="item form-group" id="dvPassport1" style="display: none">
                     <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Shipping Amount*</label>
                     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="number" id="txtPassportNumber" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $row->product_shippement_amount ?>" name="product_shippement_amount"/>
                     </div> 
                  </div>
               <div class="item form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Description <span class="required">*</span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <textarea id="textarea" required="required" name="product_description" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Description" data-validate-length-range="20"><?php echo $row->product_description ?></textarea>
                                        </div>
                </div>


                  <div class="item form-group">
                   <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Want to add specification*</label>
                   <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="Yes">
                      <input type="radio" id="Yes" name="r4" />
                      Yes
                  </label>
                   <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="No">
                      <input type="radio" id="No" name="r4" checked/>
                      No
                  </label>


               </div>
               <div class="item form-group" id="dvPassport2" style="display: none">
                     <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-xs-10">Specification*</label>
                     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <select id="txtPassportNumber1" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $row->spec_type?>" name="spec_type">
                                              <?php

                       foreach($specification as $roww)
                      {?>  
                                                <option value="<?php echo $roww->spec_id;?>"><?php echo $roww->specification_name;?></option>
                                                <?php
      }
      ?>  
                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                     <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <input type="text" id="txtPassportNumber1" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required data-validate-length-range="3" value="<?php echo $row->specification ?>" name="specification"/>
                     </div> 
                </div>
              <div class="item form-group">
                                          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="heard">Product Size<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <select id="heard" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $row->product_size ?>" name="product_size">
                                             <?php

                       foreach($size as $roww)
                      {?>  
                                                <option value="<?php echo $roww->id;?>"><?php echo $roww->size;?></option>

                                              <?php
      }
      ?>  
                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="states">Product Color*</label>
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"> 
                            <select id="colorselector" class="form-control">

                               <option value="red">Red</option>
                               <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
                               <option value="blue">Blue</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>                           
                  </div> 
                  <div class="item form-group">       
                  <div class="output">
                          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"></label>
                            <div id="red" class="colors red"> <input type="checkbox" checked/>RED </div>
                            <div id="yellow" class="colors yellow"> <input type="checkbox" checked/> YELLOW</div>
                            <div id="blue" class="colors blue"><input type="checkbox" checked/> BLUE</div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="item form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Delivery Days*</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Delivery Days" name="product_days" required value="4" value="<?php echo $row->product_days ?>">
                  Eg : (2-5)
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="item form-group">
                                          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="heard">Select Merchant<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <select id="heard" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $row->select_merchant ?>" name="select_merchant">

                                                 <?php

                       foreach($merchant as $roww)
                      {?>

          <option value="<?php echo $roww->merchant_id;?>" >

          <?php echo $roww->merchant_firstname;?></option>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                </div>
               <div class="item form-group">
                                          <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="heard">Select Shop<span class="required">*</span></label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <select id="heard" class="form-control" required value="<?php echo $row->select_shop ?>"
                                            name="select_shop">

                                                 <?php

                       foreach($merchant as $roww)
                      {?>

          <option value="<?php echo $roww->store_id;?>" >

          <?php echo $roww->store_name;?></option>
      <?php
      }
      ?>
                                            </select>
                                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Meta Keywords
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <textarea id="textarea" name="product_meta_keyword" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Meta Keywords"><?php echo $row->product_meta_keyword ?></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                 <div class="item form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Meta Description
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                            <textarea id="textarea" name="product_meta_description" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" placeholder="Meta Description"><?php echo $row->product_meta_description ?></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Product Image                                       </label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                          <input type="file" name="product_image" value=""><br>
                                          <img src="{{ url('../assets/productimage/').'/'.$row->product_image}}" style="height:90px;">


                                        </div>




                  </div>
                   <div class="item form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="textarea">Product Image                                       </label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                          <input type="file" name="product_image" value=""><br>
                                          <img src="{{ url('../assets/productimage/').'/'.$row->product_second_image}}" style="height:90px;">


                                        </div>           
                  </div> 
                            <div class="item form-group">
                          <div class="col-md-3"></div>
                          <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                                <button class="btn btn-block btn-success" type="submit">Update</button>
                            </div>
                             <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger" type="reset">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
              </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two file inputs with the name `product_image`. That's why your file is empty, and `isValid()` throws an error. You can use `hasFile()` to avoid exceptions like that.

Comment: which line i want to modify?

Comment: Rename one of your file inputs in your form.

Comment: $uploadSuccess=Input::file('product_image')->move($destinationPath,$fileName);  i was change this line like $uploadSuccess=Input::file('product_image1')->move($destinationPath,$fileName);  but it shows same error

Comment: Yes, duplicate name in your **form**

Comment: When i using hasfile() it shows following error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::hasFile()

Comment: Are you using `Input::hasFile('file_name')`?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
Input::file('image')->isValid()
```

to

```
Input::hasFile('image')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it